# Is "Logan" the last movie with Hugh Jackman as Wolverine?

Tags: x-men-cinematic-universe, casting, logan

**[Hugh Jackman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hugh_Jackman)** has played the role of **Wolverine** as a major character in various X-Men films since 2000 and contributed highly to the brand of the *X-Men* movie series. But is he playing the Wolverine character for the last time in *Logan*?

I am getting to know from my friends that **[Logan](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1430132/)** is the last movie in which he is playing Wolverine and they all say that this is his last contracted film.

Are these rumors true? Is there any official information that confirms that this is Hugh Jackman's last movie as Wolverine?

Comment: I have my doubts as to whether a contract signed between an actor and the production house would be uploaded anywhere on the internet for public knowledge.  All we can do is to listen to interviews of that actor if he spills anything.

Comment: I'm not the down voter, but I suspect it's been down-voted due to an apparent lack of research on your part to find an answer prior to you asking. Your only source is your friends, and we don't know where they heard this information from.

Comment: @Lovepreet Singh... Firstly I haven't voted on your question yet. I added comment. My best guess would be, the reason why your question was down voted was, this is more of "Entertainment Magazine". question. Its not the type of questions we deal here with. Like analysis of a plot, character etc. Please visit http://movies.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic  for further assistance.

Comment: It may also have been because of how the question was phrased.  "Is Logan the last movie..." is a question we can't answer - no one can see the future.  It might play better if you rephrased it to something like "Has Hugh Jackman stated that Logan will be his last film as Wolverine?"  Of course, the people who DV'd didn't see fit to explain why they did so (*as they are encouraged to do*), so all we can do now is guess.

Comment: @SudipBiswas Uh, in general we do *very much* deal with casting questions here, too.

Comment: This seems like a reasonable question about an actor's contract and his future in a role  and films series that he defined. This seems neither encouraging opinion, nor does it seem irrelevant trivia, nor is it off-topic. It is a classic casting/production question.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson..Oops!!!...I wasn't aware of that. My apologies.:)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Will it be the last time?

Until further confirmation, yes.

> **“This will be my last one,” Jackman said, point blank, when asked about it on the Dr. Oz show earlier today.**
>
> “It is my last time,” he continued. “It just felt like it was the right time to do it. And let’s be honest, 17 years. I never thought in a million years it would last, so I’m so grateful to the fans for the opportunity of playing it.
>
> “I kind of have in my head what we’re going to do in this last one. It just feels like this is the perfect way to go out.”

[Hugh Jackman Confirms Wolverine 3 Will Be His Last Time As Character](http://comicbook.com/2015/05/07/hugh-jackman-confirms-wolverine-3-will-be-his-last-time-as-chara/)

Answer (score 11):

#### No.

On Sept. 2022, Ryan Reynolds and Hugh Jackman announced on Ryan's Twitter account: ([tweet 1](https://twitter.com/vancityreynolds/status/1574865217141481477)) ([tweet 2](https://twitter.com/VancityReynolds/status/1575101936700772355)), that Hugh Jackman will reprise his role as Wolverine in a third Deadpool film to be released in 2024. This Deadpool film will be set in the Marvel Cinematic Universe.

> While many beloved comic book stars have been played by multiple
> actors, there’s really only been one Wolverine in the movies. “Well, I
> was greedy,” Jackman says. “I held on to it for 20 years. And then, of
> course, since I left, it’s been bought by Disney. I’m sure the plans
> are afoot.”
>
> A few weeks later, I talk to Jackman on the phone, and those plans are
> clear. “I straight-up lied,” he says. “But you’re not the only one I
> lied to, let me tell you.”
>
> He really meant it when he said he was retiring as Wolverine. But then
> in 2016, “I went to a screening of ‘Deadpool.’ I was 20 minutes in,
> and I was like, ‘Ah, damn it!’ All I kept seeing in my head was ‘48
> Hours’ with Nick Nolte and Eddie Murphy. So it’s been brewing for a
> long time. It just took me longer to get here.”
>
> At the end of August, during a road trip to the beach with his family,
> he finally made the decision. He called Reynolds, who’d been pleading
> “on the daily” for a Wolverine-Deadpool movie. “I think, actually,
> he’d given up,” Jackman says. “I think it was a big shock to him.
> There was a massive pause, and then he said, ‘I can’t believe the
> timing of this.’”
>
> Reynolds was about to meet with Marvel Studios president Kevin Feige
> about “Deadpool 3.” With Jackman in, the rest is comic book movie
> history.
>
> “Oh my God, I’m thrilled,” Reynolds tells me. “It’s like old home
> week. To get to be on set with one of my closest friends each and
> every day is a dream come true. But to do it with these two iconic
> characters side by side, that’s beyond our wildest dreams.” Reynolds
> adds that the first time he talked to Feige — three and a half years
> ago after Disney bought Fox — he’d pushed for bringing in Wolverine.
> “It wasn’t possible then,” Reynolds says. “For this to be happening
> now is pretty damn exciting.”

<sup>— [*The Story of Hugh Jackman in Five Acts*. Variety](https://variety.com/2022/film/features/hugh-jackman-dad-death-the-son-wolverine-1235413831/)</sup>